# Elegant exception handling in ltng:outAppUnstyled

Tags: lightning-out

I am using `ltng:outAppUnstyled` to create re-usable bi-style (LEX and Classic) components.

However whenever some sort of exception occurs, it just gets appended the the bottom of app body:

```
<div id="auraErrorMessage">This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: NameSpace:myComponentName$controller$methodName [foo]
Failing descriptor: {MyNameSpace:myComponentName $controller$methodName}</div>
```

And looks like this:

[image]

Basically it is invisible to the user (and many times - even my self).

What could be a good way to style this? There are no classes, just some id. Polling the DOM for id doesn't seem like a very good idea. Perhaps there is some sort of event I can subscribe to in my Visualforce container?

Edit: So far the best I could do is use getElementById in createComponent callback (fortunately div exists before actual errors are printed) and make add standard VF error class names and event listener that hides message when you click on div. Not the best experience, but oh well. Hide message otherwise with the following selector `div#clearAuraErrorMessage:empty`.

**Final edit**: Below is the complete solution

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />
        <div id="lightning"/>
        <script>              $Lightning.use("NameSpace:LightningOutApp", function() {      
            $Lightning.createComponent("NameSpace:MyComponent",{},"lightning",
            function(cmp) {
              var target = document.getElementById('auraErrorMessage');
              target.className="message errorM3 floatingError"
              target.ondblclick= function(){
                this.innerHTML='';
              }
            });
          });
        </script>
        <style>
          .floatingError {
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 20vw;
            height: 10vw;
            z-index: 9998;
            margin: 0 auto;
          }
          .floatingError:after {
            content: "(Double click to dismiss)";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: -1;
          }
          div#auraErrorMessage:empty {
            display: none;
          }
        </style>
</apex:page>
```

It's appear like this:
[image]